# Aggregate WSO2 CEP Siddhi events to a single json object

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, siddhi, wso2-cep

I'm trying to build an execution plan which aggregates different events into one and counts the occurrence (CurrentEventId). The plan looks like the following:

```
define stream inStream (correlation_EventName string, LastEventId int, CurrentEventId int);

partition with (CurrentEventId of inStream)
begin

    from inStream#window.timeBatch(10 sec)
    select correlation_EventName as meta_Label, CurrentEventId as meta_Id, LastEventId as correlation_From, CurrentEventId as correlation_To, count(CurrentEventId) as correlation_Value
    insert into outStream

end;
```

Actually, I have the following output:

```
Event: {"event":{"metaData":{"Label":"StartCalculationEvent","Id":2},"correlationData":{"From":2,"To":2,"Value":66}}}
Event: {"event":{"metaData":{"Label":"LoginEvent","Id":1},"correlationData":{"From":1,"To":1,"Value":693}}}
```

I need just a **single** event every 10 seconds and not multiple events. This event should have the following format:

```
[
    {
        "event":{"metaData":"..."}
    },
    {
        "event":{"metaData":"..."}
    }
]
```

Do you have an idea on how to realize that?

Answer (score 0):

With siddhi partitions, separate events will be generated for each partition variable(in this case the `CurrentEventId`). Since you have two CurrentEventIds, you receive two events into outStream. If there were three CurrentEventIds you would have received 3 events separately.

As of now, there is no way to batch events in siddhi as you have requested. There is a related [Jira](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CEP-256) which is similar to the functionality you are expecting.